# Why is the sequence 1,4,13,40,121... more efficient then 1,2,4,8,16... when insertion-sorting?

Tags: algorithm, math, sorting

1,4,13,40,121...((3 * n) + 1) works slightly more efficiently than 1,2,4,8,16...(2 * n) when inserting random numbers to a sorting algorithm.

Why is this? Is it anything to do with threading?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with threading, but +1 to know answers, interesting.

Comment: Curious research extended from homework, so in a way yes.

Comment: What does mean "slightly more efficiently"?

Comment: I am measuring the efficiency by counting array assignment operations, and the latter sequence produces c.3% more than the former, using an array of size 5000.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, talking about the step sizes in a Shell sort, rather than a pure insertion sort?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you comparing the efficiency with the same value of n across both the sequences ?

Comment: Yes, n is the size of the array, which increases by 50 with each loop iteration, up to the maximum of 5000. Both sequences use the same array and array alteration logic.

Comment: I don't mean the n in the sequences by the way, I mean the n in the sort logic.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that the shell sort increment steps of 2^k, 2^(k-1), ..., 1 are one of the worst. For instance, you only compare the elements at the odd positions, with the ones at the even positions only at the last step!

The other steps seem to be (3^k -1)/2 (and not 3n+1) and don't suffer from problems like the even/odd issue. That is not a proof, but we might expect this to be better than powers of 2.

If you are looking for mathematical analysis, Shell Sort is well known for giving mathematicians a hard time.

I didn't find any analysis of your sequence in Sedgewick's paper [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/shell/). Perhap one of Knuth's books has it.

Good luck.

btw, why do you ask about threading?

Comment: @Moron: (@kymully:) he writes `2*n` and `3*n+1` but he means `a(n+1)=2*a(n)` and `a(n+1)=3*a(n)+1`.